# How to change Option color?

Tags: javascript, html, google-apps-script

I have an array of 'option' sourced from google spreadsheet.

However, I am unable to change its font color in my html.

here is my code for html :-

```
<div class="row">  

        <div class="input-field">
          <input list="browsers" name="browser" id="mail" type="email" class="validate">
          <datalist id="browsers">
          <? for(var i=0;i<list1.length;i++){ ?>

      <option class="color:white"><?= list1[i]; ?></option>

      <? } ?>
  </datalist>

            <label for="mail">Email: 'abc@gmail.com'</label>
            <span class="grey-text helper-text" data-error="please provide agent ladap in this format- 'ldap@google.com'" data-success="right"></span>
        </div>

      </div>
```

I tried [ class="color:white" ] in option field but is does not do the job.

Comment: styling up the combos is different a bit than you think, you need to hide original combo, and make usage of :after pseudo classes, pls refer to https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_custom_select.asp

Comment: class? Shouldn't it be `style`?

Comment: yes, typo, it's style not class

Comment: @Raphael your first answer is correct but I am using materializecss which is making it harder to change color. I tried your first method some how got the result but now there are two fields automatically created for select. I guess due to materialize plugin its giving error.